# Submit button do not work in angularjs when I use templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I load the main page, it will load the third section of this page [ `/login GET HTTP request` ] inside of the ng-view of the div of the main page. My problem is when I click on submit button, It won't submit the given page and call login() function inside of `InitCtrl` controller

**This is the main page:**

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="mvc-module">
<head>
         <script src='<c:url value="/static/angular.js"/>'></script>
         <script src='<c:url value="/static/todo.js"/>'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**todo.js:**

```
angular.module("mvc-module", []).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {controller: InitCtrl, template: '<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="mainPage"</div>'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

function InitCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("login").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.mainPage = data; // for see the response see /log GET response
    });

    $scope.login = function () {
    $http.post("login", {password: $scope.password, username: $scope.username}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.mainPage = data;
            console.log("successfully logged to login");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error in post");
        });
    };
}
```

**This is response of /login GET HTTP request :**

```
<div>
    <form class="form-signin" ng-submit="login()">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="User name" ng-model="username">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" ng-model="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u see the html in the correct place in the page? Is it in the correct div & formatted correctly?

Comment: @FooL yes I see it correctly

Comment: What if you put `ng-click="login()"` in the button instead?

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

by

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Sign in</button>
```

Or, change `<button>` to `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: This is not solution,I have still the problem